# Laravel - Undefined index: Id

Tags: php, laravel

In my blade I am echoing a shipping ID. If I use "dd()" it dumps the number correctly. When I try to echo it I get error: "Undefined index: Id" I am puzzled why an error would throw if dd() works.

```
dd($shipping['Id']);
```

Outputs: 1234

```
echo $shipping['Id'];
```

Outputs: Error: Undefined index: Id

Comment: `var_dump($shipping);`

Comment: Are you using loop?

Comment: @AbraCadaver https://ideone.com/I0AW74

Comment: @Davit yes I have a foreach, I think that might be the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using you code in `foreach`. When `dd($shipping['Id']);` that is first loop and first `$shipping` contains `'Id'`, When using echo $shipping['Id'] you get error because one of `$shipping` does not contain `id`. For fix it use in blade use

```
@if(!empty($shipping['Id']))
    {{$shipping['Id']}}
@endif
```

or

```
echo $shipping['Id'] ?? '';
```